# NavigationView and NavigationLink on button click in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to push from login view to detail view but not able to make it.even navigation bar is not showing in login view. How to push on button click in SwiftUI? How to use NavigationLink on button click?

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Let's get you signed in.")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .topLeading)
                .padding(Edge.Set.bottom, 50)
            
            Text("Email address:")
                .font(.headline)
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .frame(height:44)
                .accentColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
                .cornerRadius(4.0)
            
            Text("Password:")
                .font(.headline)
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .frame(height:44)
                .accentColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
                .cornerRadius(4.0)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("login tapped")
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Login").foregroundColor(Color.white).bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .accentColor(Color.black)
            .padding()
            .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
            .cornerRadius(4.0)
            .padding(Edge.Set.vertical, 20)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal,30)
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To fix your issue you need to bind and manage tag with `NavigationLink`, So create one state inside you view as follow, just add above body.

```
@State var selection: Int? = nil
```

Then update your button code as follow to add `NavigationLink`

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Test"), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
    Button(action: {
        print("login tapped")
        self.selection = 1
    }) {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Login").foregroundColor(Color.white).bold()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .accentColor(Color.black)
    .padding()
    .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
    .cornerRadius(4.0)
    .padding(Edge.Set.vertical, 20)
}
```

Meaning is, when selection and `NavigationLink` tag value will match then navigation will be occurs.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i  tried to use it. but how actually write it on button click. because i am getting errors.

Comment: You don't actually need the *tag+selection* variant. There is a simpler *isActive* variant - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367285/8697793)

Comment: @pawello2222 `isActive` seems to be hard to get working when you want the navigation to be triggered by a button click. I find the method in this answer perfect for such a use case.

Comment: this is working only when having navigationLink inside NavigationView.

Answer (score 65):

### iOS 16+

*Note: Below is a simplified example of how to present a new view. For a more advanced generic example please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530071/8697793).*

In iOS 16 we can access the [NavigationStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) and [NavigationPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationpath).

**Usage #1**

A new view is activated by a simple `NavigationLink`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(value: "NewView") {
                Text("Show NewView")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                if view == "NewView" {
                    Text("This is NewView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage #2**

A new view is activated by a standard `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Button {
                path.append("NewView")
            } label: {
                Text("Show NewView")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                if view == "NewView" {
                    Text("This is NewView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage #3**

A new view is activated programmatically:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("Content View")
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                    if view == "NewView" {
                        Text("This is NewView")
                    }
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            path.append("NewView")
        }
    }
}
```

---

### iOS 13+

The accepted answer uses `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)` which is correct.

However, for a simple view with just one `NavigationLink` you can use a **simpler** variant: `NavigationLink(destination:isActive:)`

**Usage #1**

`NavigationLink` is activated by a standard `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ...
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("OtherView"), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isLinkActive = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage #2**

`NavigationLink` is *hidden* and activated by a standard `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ...
                Button(action: {
                    self.isLinkActive = true
                }) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("OtherView"), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .hidden()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage #3**

`NavigationLink` is *hidden* and activated programmatically:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ...
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Login"))
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("OtherView"), isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .hidden()
            )
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.isLinkActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/PhantomKit#highlights) with different SwiftUI extensions that makes navigation easier.</sub>

Comment: A hidden NavigationLink to control programmatic segues was a revelation. Thank you!

Comment: Usage #2 worked when using the new iOS Menu feature to programmatically go to a NavLink. @pawello2222 - genius.

Comment: Wow, Apple really made NavigationView confusing.

Comment: Wait, Is `NavigationLink(destination:isActive:)` not suitable for the view that has more than 1 NavigationLinks?

Comment: @user482594 You can easily use multiple `NavigationLink(destination:isActive:)` in one view - controlled by multiple `@State` variables. This works best if the links are independent from each other. However, the `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)` may be more suitable for cases when you need to add multiple *related* NavigationLinks - like in a list etc.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. It still really blows my mind how Apple manages to make something this trivial as changing views as ugly as this. They always manage.

Comment: @Azurlake yeah this is ridiculous, you should be able to navigate to a different view from a button press (self.present(MyNewView())), much simpler than using `@State` properties everywhere

Answer (score 10):

Another approach:

**SceneDelegate**

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: BaseView().environmentObject(ViewRouter()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

**BaseView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct BaseView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "view1" {
                FirstView()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPage == "view2" {
                SecondView()
                    .transition(.scale)
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct MotherView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BaseView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
#endif
```

**ViewRouter**

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>()

    var currentPage: String = "view1" {
        didSet {
            withAnimation() {
                objectWillChange.send(self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {self.viewRouter.currentPage = "view2"}) {
                NextButtonContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct FirstView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
#endif

struct NextButtonContent : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Next")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding(.top, 50)
    }
}
```

**SecondView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 50.0)
            Button(action: {self.viewRouter.currentPage = "view1"}) {
                BackButtonContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SecondView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
#endif

struct BackButtonContent : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Back")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding(.top, 50)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

We should use NavigationStack instead of NavigationView, that's the new way to handle the navigation using the button in SwiftUI.

You need to use the state property wrapper for navigation as follows

```
@State private var isShowingDashboardView = false
```

then use the following code.

```
    NavigationStack {
      VStack{
         Button(action: {
           isShowingDashboardView = true
         }) {
           Text("Login")
         }
      }
       .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isShowingDashboardView, destination: { DashboardView()})
    }
```

Comment: `NavigationsStack` requires iOS 16+

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion a cleaner way for **iOS 16+** is using a state bool to present the view.

```
struct ButtonNavigationView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSecondView : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack{
                Button(action:{isShowingSecondView = true} ){
                    Text("Show second view")
                }
            }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $isShowingSecondView) {
                Text("SecondView")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest and most effective solution is :**

```
NavigationLink(destination:ScoresTableView()) {
                    Text("Scores")
                }.navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 45, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 110 , bottom: 16, trailing: 20))
```

**ScoresTableView is the destination view.**

Answer (score 0):

I think above answers are nice, but simpler way should be:

```
    NavigationLink {
        TargetView()
    } label: {
        Text("Click to go")
    }
```