# Use Combine to route SwiftUI Views

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am trying to use Combine to route SwiftUI views, and it sort of works, but has some unwanted behaviour that I hope someone can help me with. I made an [example project](https://github.com/imyrvold/RouteTest/tree/main/RouteTest) which only contains two files, `ViewRouter.swift` and `ViewController.swift` that just contains a `@IBSegueAction` to return a `UIHostingController`:

The class `ViewRouter` is a `ViewModel` for the SwiftUI Views that contains a `@ViewBuilder` property. When the `SwiftUI` views calls the `didFinish()` function, the `step` property is set to the next `View`.

```swift
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    enum Step { case test1, test2, test3, test4 }
    @Published var step: Step = .test1
    @ViewBuilder var nextStepView: some View {
        switch step {
        case .test1:
            Test1(router: self)
        case .test2:
            Test2(router: self)
        case .test3:
            Test3(router: self)
        case .test4:
            Test4(router: self)
        }
    }
    
    func didFinish() {
        switch step {
        case .test1:
            step = .test2
        case .test2:
            step = .test3
        case .test3:
            step = .test4
        case .test4:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfect for `Test1`, when tapping the `Next` link, the `Test1` view is animated to the left, to reveal `Test2`. When tapping `Next` in `Test2` however, the `Test2` is animated to the left to reveal `Test3`, but then immediately it animates back to the right to reveal the same `Test3` view. Exactly the same happens when tapping `Next` in `Test3`.

And tapping the back button always ends up in `Test1` view.

All four views are the same, apart from the text in `Text`:

```swift
struct Test1: View {
    @ObservedObject var router: ViewRouter
    @State var nextView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: router.nextStepView, isActive: $nextView) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            Text("Test1")
            
            Button(action: {
                nextView = true
                router.didFinish()
            }, label: {
                Text("Next")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909832/12299030.

Comment: Since a `struct` is a key piece of a valid `View` I would assume that trying to "build views" in a `class` would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some small changes to the ViewRouter class to make this work. I came to the conclusion that all SwiftUI views need their own ViewRouter instance. Using the same shared instance of ViewRouter for all views results in the unwanted behaviour. I have introduced a `nextStep` optional property that is set to the current step when a view calls the `didFinish` function, to make sure that the router returns correct `nextStepView` if called a second or third etc times.

I have pushed an update to the GitHub repo for the example Xcode project.

The modified class now looks like this:

```swift
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    enum Step { case test1, test2, test3, test4 }
    @Published var step: Step
    private var nextStep: Step?
    @ViewBuilder var nextStepView: some View {
        switch step {
        case .test1:
            Test1(router: self)
        case .test2:
            Test2(router: ViewRouter(step: .test2))
        case .test3:
            Test3(router: ViewRouter(step: .test3))
        case .test4:
            Test4(router: ViewRouter(step: .test4))
        }
    }
    
    init(step: Step) {
        self.step = step
    }
    
    func didFinish() {
        switch step {
        case .test1:
            if let next = nextStep {
                step = next
            } else {
                step = .test2
                nextStep = .test2
            }
        case .test2:
            if let next = nextStep {
                step = next
            } else {
                step = .test3
                nextStep = .test3
            }
        case .test3:
            if let next = nextStep {
                step = next
            } else {
                step = .test4
                nextStep = .test4
            }
        case .test4:
            break
        }
    }
    
}
```