# Determine NavigationLink Destination During Initialization

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to determine the destination of a `NavigationLink` of SwiftUI dynamically within `init()` based on the generic data provided to the view.

Based on the code below, if the `Item` is a `Tour` the destination should be a `TourDetailView` and otherwise a `LocationDetailView`.

```
struct CardView<Item: CardItem>: View {
  let card: Item
  private let destination: T
  
  init(card: Item) {
    self.card = card

    if Item.self == Tour.self {
      destination = TourDetailView(tour: card as! Tour) as! T
    } else {
      destination = LocationDetailView(location: card as! Location) as! T
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Right now the code is not compiling because `T` isn't defined. If I define `T` as:

`struct CardView<Item: CardItem, T: View>: View {`

`CardView` is handled but then I have to edit the View calling the CardView which both introduces unnecessary complexity and eventually I have to define T in `@main` which is not allowed.

How can I achieve what I want? I tried to make `destination` another type but with no success.

Comment: This topic should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304700/swiftui-how-to-avoid-navigation-hardcoded-into-the-view.

Comment: The accepted answer solves ym problem. Actually, I tried `AnyView` before myself but was trying to stay away from it for a more elegant solution. Your sugegstion might help me. Thanks. @Asperi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo to fix your issue.. just store the View in a property with type `AnyView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let destination: AnyView

    init() {
      // This is just demo purpose, here comes your condition
      if false {
        destination = AnyView(DetailViewA())
      } else {
        destination = AnyView(DetailViewB())
      }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: destination,
                label: {
                    Text("Navigate")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct DetailViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("A")
    }
}

struct DetailViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("B")
    }
}
```

Comment: I should've mentioned this in my question. I actually tried `AnyView` before. I wanted to stay away from it since I lose some type safety but I guess there it no other way. Appreciate it! @davidev