# How to navigate after few seconds in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Need some extra help with SwiftUI and navigating between views.

In one view, I have a button with `ImagePicker`:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImageAndNavigate) {
    ImagePicker(image: $image, isShown: $showingImagePicker, sourceType: sourceType)
}
```

and when the user chooses or takes an image, on dismiss I want to show some spinner until image will be classified, and later to navigate and send this image to another view.

How can I navigate to another view from `loadImageAndNavigate` func?

Comment: Create some variable responsible for showing your other view and set it to `true` in `loadImageAndNavigate`. Then activate a `NavigationLink` programatically like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367285/8697793