# SwiftUI for macOS: Expand clickable area of a TextField in a ForEach view of a List

Tags: list, macos, swiftui, foreach, textfield

As a hobby project, I'm developing a SwiftUI app targeted for macOS.

I have a CoreData entity (let's call it `Sample`) with a `String` property called `title`.

In my main view (`SamplesView`) I'm displaying a `List` of `Sample`s, and I want `title`s be editable directly from the list. For that, I've made a sub-view (`SampleRowView`) with a `TextField`, and I'm displaying this sub-view in the `List` using `ForEach`.

It works and looks okayish. Though, I can edit the `title` only if I click directly on the `TextField`'s text (point 1 on the screenshot). If I click on the "empty" part of the `TextField` (f.e. point 2) it does not  respond. I thought that the shape of the `TextField` is limited somehow by the length of its text, but as visible on the screenshot,  `TextField` occupies the whole row.

Appreciate any help and ideas about how to make the `TextField` respond to click on its any point, not only on the text.

[image: Screenshot of the list]

```swift
// "Sample" is a CoreData entity
public class Sample: NSManagedObject {
//...
  @NSManaged public var title: String
}


// This is the main view
struct SamplesView: View {
  @FetchRequest(...)
  var samples: FetchedResults<Sample>

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      List {
        ForEach(samples) { sample in 
          SampleRowView(sample: sample)
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteSample)
      }
    }
  }
}

// List rows with editable Sample's title
struct SampleRowView: View {
  @ObservedObject var sample: Sample
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("", text: $sample.title)
  }
}
```

### Update:

The problem is the same even on the fresh project. Also, if I change `TextField` with `TextEditor` the behavior is kinda expected.

Digging a bit more into it:
[TextField inside a List in SwiftUI on macOS: Editing not working well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460596/textfield-inside-a-list-in-swiftui-on-macos-editing-not-working-well)

[Editable TextField in SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576128/editable-textfield-in-swiftui-list)

[SwiftUI make ForEach List row properly clickable for edition in EditMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088883/swiftui-make-foreach-list-row-properly-clickable-for-edition-in-editmode)

I've found that it seems to be a bug in SwiftUI, and for now the only solution is to somehow replace the `List` with `ScrollView` with custom item moving and deletion. This is sad.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Sample: Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  var title: String
  init(id: Int) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = "Sample \(id)"
  }
}

struct TestView: View {
  @State var samples = [Sample(id: 1), Sample(id: 2)]
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach($samples) { $sample in
        TextField("", text: $sample.title) // .textFieldStyle(.squareBorder) -- doesn't help
//        TextEditor(text: $sample.title) // This works as expected
        }
      }
    }
}

@main
struct SampleApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      TestView()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using XCode Version 13.2.1, Swift 5, MacOS deployment target 11.6.

Comment: The code you posted does not appear to have this problem. There must be something else, not shown, causing the problem.  If you click to the right of the text, the insertion point goes to the end of the text.

Comment: I can replicate your issue. It works for me if you add to your `TextField`, `.textFieldStyle(.squareBorder)`   or `.roundedBorder`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately neither of these helps. I even created a new project and the behavior is the same. (XCode Version 13.2.1)

Comment: FYI, your new example code with the `.textFieldStyle(.squareBorder)` 
works well for me, on macos 12.3, using xcode 13.3, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12 and also macOS 12.3 only.  
It seems to be different (not working) on older systems, such as macos 11.6.

Comment: Adding .squareBorder is also working for me. However, I don't like the style it creates. ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@FocusState private var textFieldFocused: Bool

TextField()
 .contentShape(Rectangle())
 .padding(
        EdgeInsets(
            top: 15,
            leading: 10,
            bottom: 15,
            trailing: 10)
    )
 .focused($textFieldFocused)
 .onTapGesture {
  textFieldFocused = true
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

to your View element.

I use it along with Text()-Instances which allows me to accept clicks not only on the written part of the View element, but everywhere within its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

@david solution worked for me, but I had to modify it. Removed the `.padding` and added `.frame`.
I have a `CurrencyField`, maybe the original with `TextField` will work.

```swift
CurrencyField(value: $value)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 35, alignment: .trailing)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .focused($textFieldFocused)
    .onTapGesture {
        textFieldFocused = true
    }
```

The `.frame` is now the clickable area.

Xcode 15.0 / Swift 5 / iOS 17.0